# SVG image is displayed differently in browsers

Tags: html, css, svg

I have got SVG image, but it's displayed differently in different browsers:

- **Google Chrome *(66.0.3359.181)*** - part of image (flag) is hidden
- **Firefox *(58.0.2)*** - part of image (flag) is displayed as rectangle
- **Edge *(41.16299.371.0)*** - image displayed correctly

I also prepared test code, where you can try it yourself:

```
<html>
    <head></head>

    <body style="background-color:black;">
        <svg style="width:0; height:0; position:absolute; visibility:hidden;">
            <symbol id="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 304 60"><path d="M132.46 53.11c5.02 3.93 10.82 5.89 17.42 5.89 5.77 0 10.92-1.47 15.45-4.4m-31.42-17.26l4.92 2.76.1 4.55-1.4 4.5 3.2 5.75-4.05-2.7-2.92-4.15m44.37-16.1l-6.45-13-2.3 7.15-1.9-3.35-3.05 5.1 3.6 2.9-4.15 2.65-5.15-5.1.65-1.45-3.15-2.25h-3.5l-1.8-1.05-4.85 2.9-.35-2.75 1.05-1.45 3.6-1.65.85-1.8 2.55 1.4 2.45-4.15-2.25-1.6-1.4 2.05-2.8-1.6 4.15-4 3.5 1.4 2.35-.9 2.55-7.35c-3.77-1.8-7.92-2.7-12.45-2.7-1.23 0-2.42.05-3.55.15l2.2 2.8-2.7 5.95-5.5 2.9 1.1-7.4-4.2-1.6a27.05 27.05 0 0 0-5.9 3.95l5.7.5-1.4 6.25-4-1.45-1.55 1.7 4.75 2.7v4.1l-3.1 1-3.74 6.13m-6.31-4.96c1.11-5.39 3.74-10.16 7.9-14.32.43-.5.93-.98 1.5-1.45.1-.03.18-.1.25-.2m15-6.6c-2.23.23-4.35.7-6.35 1.4-.97.4-1.88.82-2.75 1.25m40.9 27.8s.45-3 0-6c-.99-6.57-2.98-11.33-7.85-16.2-1.13-1.1-2.27-2.08-3.4-2.95a30.598 30.598 0 0 0-4.55-2.75m-11.7 24.05l.7 1.8 5.15.35 6.7 7.3-3.45 3.9v3.1l-4.9 5.45-1.45-.15-3.6-11.9-3.4.85-4.2-3.6 2.9-4.45 5.55-2.65zm10.15 21.05l2.6-3.25m9.9-14.9l.8-1.35m-27.7-11.9l-2.9 2.65M204.07 50.47c.06-.86.09-2.02.09-3.49 0-1.9-.04-3.26-.13-4.09-.06-1.55-.22-2.9-.47-4.05-.2-.92-.65-1.69-1.34-2.33-.69-.63-1.49-.99-2.41-1.08-1.81-.23-3.88-.37-6.2-.43h-13.14c-2.41.06-4.57.2-6.46.43-.89.09-1.67.45-2.33 1.08-.69.63-1.15 1.41-1.38 2.33-.26 1.15-.43 2.5-.52 4.05-.06.89-.09 2.26-.09 4.09 0 1.81.03 3.17.09 4.09.09 1.55.26 2.89.52 4.01.2.95.66 1.74 1.38 2.37.66.57 1.44.93 2.33 1.08 1.9.17 4.05.3 6.46.39 1.44.06 3.59.09 6.46.09s5.03-.03 6.46-.09c2.41-.09 4.55-.22 6.42-.39.89-.14 1.69-.5 2.41-1.08.69-.63 1.12-1.42 1.29-2.37.29-1.12.46-2.46.52-4.01.03-.2.04-.4.04-.6zm-21.63-9.57l10.94 5.73-10.94 5.69V40.9z" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="3"></path><defs><circle id="a" cx="115.91" cy="42.93" r="16.07"></circle></defs><clipPath id="b"><use xlink:href="#a" overflow="visible"></use></clipPath><g clip-path="url(#b)"><path fill="#fff" d="M93.6 25.33h52.14v34.92H93.6z"></path><g fill="#eb2227"><path d="M93.6 25.33h52.14v2.74H93.6zM93.6 30.69h52.14v2.74H93.6zM93.6 36.06h52.14v2.74H93.6zM93.6 41.42h52.14v2.74H93.6zM93.6 46.78h52.14v2.74H93.6zM93.6 52.15h52.14v2.74H93.6zM93.6 57.51h52.14v2.74H93.6z"></path></g><path fill="#303287" d="M93.6 25.33h23.47v18.83H93.6z"></path><g fill="#fff"><path d="M95.53 27.6l.59.43-.22-.7.59-.43h-.73l-.23-.7-.23.7h-.73l.6.43-.23.7zM99.45 27.6l.59.43-.22-.7.59-.43h-.73l-.23-.7-.22.7h-.74l.6.43-.23.7zM103.37 27.6l.6.43-.23-.7.59-.43h-.73l-.23-.7-.22.7h-.73l.59.43-.23.7zM107.3 27.6l.59.43-.23-.7.59-.43h-.73l-.22-.7-.23.7h-.73l.59.43-.23.7zM111.22 27.6l.59.43-.23-.7.6-.43h-.74l-.22-.7-.23.7h-.73l.59.43-.23.7zM115.14 27.6l.59.43-.23-.7.6-.43h-.74l-.22-.7-.23.7h-.73l.59.43-.23.7zM97.49 29.49l.6.43-.23-.69.59-.43h-.73l-.23-.7-.23.7h-.73l.6.43-.23.69zM101.41 29.49l.6.43-.23-.69.59-.43h-.73l-.23-.7-.22.7h-.74l.6.43-.23.69zM105.33 29.49l.6.43-.23-.69.59-.43h-.73l-.23-.7-.22.7h-.73l.59.43-.23.69zM109.26 29.49l.59.43-.23-.69.59-.43h-.73l-.22-.7-.23.7h-.73l.59.43-.23.69zM113.18 29.49l.59.43-.23-.69.6-.43h-.74l-.22-.7-.23.7h-.73l.59.43-.23.69zM95.53 31.39l.59.43-.22-.7.59-.43h-.73l-.23-.7-.23.7h-.73l.6.43-.23.7zM99.45 31.39l.59.43-.22-.7.59-.43h-.73l-.23-.7-.22.7h-.74l.6.43-.23.7zM103.37 31.39l.6.43-.23-.7.59-.43h-.73l-.23-.7-.22.7h-.73l.59.43-.23.7zM107.3 31.39l.59.43-.23-.7.59-.43h-.73l-.22-.7-.23.7h-.73l.59.43-.23.7zM111.22 31.39l.59.43-.23-.7.6-.43h-.74l-.22-.7-.23.7h-.73l.59.43-.23.7zM115.14 31.39l.59.43-.23-.7.6-.43h-.74l-.22-.7-.23.7h-.73l.59.43-.23.7zM97.49 33.28l.6.43-.23-.7.59-.43h-.73l-.23-.69-.23.69h-.73l.6.43-.23.7zM101.41 33.28l.6.43-.23-.7.59-.43h-.73l-.23-.69-.22.69h-.74l.6.43-.23.7zM105.33 33.28l.6.43-.23-.7.59-.43h-.73l-.23-.69-.22.69h-.73l.59.43-.23.7zM109.26 33.28l.59.43-.23-.7.59-.43h-.73l-.22-.69-.23.69h-.73l.59.43-.23.7zM113.18 33.28l.59.43-.23-.7.6-.43h-.74l-.22-.69-.23.69h-.73l.59.43-.23.7zM95.53 35.18l.59.43-.22-.7.59-.43h-.73l-.23-.7-.23.7h-.73l.6.43-.23.7zM99.45 35.18l.59.43-.22-.7.59-.43h-.73l-.23-.7-.22.7h-.74l.6.43-.23.7zM103.37 35.18l.6.43-.23-.7.59-.43h-.73l-.23-.7-.22.7h-.73l.59.43-.23.7zM107.3 35.18l.59.43-.23-.7.59-.43h-.73l-.22-.7-.23.7h-.73l.59.43-.23.7zM111.22 35.18l.59.43-.23-.7.6-.43h-.74l-.22-.7-.23.7h-.73l.59.43-.23.7zM115.14 35.18l.59.43-.23-.7.6-.43h-.74l-.22-.7-.23.7h-.73l.59.43-.23.7zM97.49 37.07l.6.43-.23-.7.59-.43h-.73l-.23-.7-.23.7h-.73l.6.43-.23.7zM101.41 37.07l.6.43-.23-.7.59-.43h-.73l-.23-.7-.22.7h-.74l.6.43-.23.7zM105.33 37.07l.6.43-.23-.7.59-.43h-.73l-.23-.7-.22.7h-.73l.59.43-.23.7zM109.26 37.07l.59.43-.23-.7.59-.43h-.73l-.22-.7-.23.7h-.73l.59.43-.23.7zM113.18 37.07l.59.43-.23-.7.6-.43h-.74l-.22-.7-.23.7h-.73l.59.43-.23.7zM95.53 38.96l.59.43-.22-.69.59-.43h-.73l-.23-.7-.23.7h-.73l.6.43-.23.69zM99.45 38.96l.59.43-.22-.69.59-.43h-.73l-.23-.7-.22.7h-.74l.6.43-.23.69zM103.37 38.96l.6.43-.23-.69.59-.43h-.73l-.23-.7-.22.7h-.73l.59.43-.23.69zM107.3 38.96l.59.43-.23-.69.59-.43h-.73l-.22-.7-.23.7h-.73l.59.43-.23.69zM111.22 38.96l.59.43-.23-.69.6-.43h-.74l-.22-.7-.23.7h-.73l.59.43-.23.69zM115.14 38.96l.59.43-.23-.69.6-.43h-.74l-.22-.7-.23.7h-.73l.59.43-.23.69zM97.49 40.86l.6.43-.23-.7.59-.43h-.73l-.23-.7-.23.7h-.73l.6.43-.23.7zM101.41 40.86l.6.43-.23-.7.59-.43h-.73l-.23-.7-.22.7h-.74l.6.43-.23.7zM105.33 40.86l.6.43-.23-.7.59-.43h-.73l-.23-.7-.22.7h-.73l.59.43-.23.7zM109.26 40.86l.59.43-.23-.7.59-.43h-.73l-.22-.7-.23.7h-.73l.59.43-.23.7zM113.18 40.86l.59.43-.23-.7.6-.43h-.74l-.22-.7-.23.7h-.73l.59.43-.23.7zM95.53 42.75l.59.43-.22-.69.59-.43h-.73l-.23-.7-.23.7h-.73l.6.43-.23.69zM99.45 42.75l.59.43-.22-.69.59-.43h-.73l-.23-.7-.22.7h-.74l.6.43-.23.69zM103.37 42.75l.6.43-.23-.69.59-.43h-.73l-.23-.7-.22.7h-.73l.59.43-.23.69zM107.3 42.75l.59.43-.23-.69.59-.43h-.73l-.22-.7-.23.7h-.73l.59.43-.23.69zM111.22 42.75l.59.43-.23-.69.6-.43h-.74l-.22-.7-.23.7h-.73l.59.43-.23.69zM115.14 42.75l.59.43-.23-.69.6-.43h-.74l-.22-.7-.23.7h-.73l.59.43-.23.69z"></path></g><path fill="none" stroke="#231f20" stroke-width="1.5" d="M93.6 25.33h52.14v34.92H93.6z"></path></g></symbol></svg>

        <svg>
            <use xlink:href="#icon"></use>
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

*I used black background, bcs the image is white*

https://jsfiddle.net/p7fnne2L/

As you can see, I used SVG image as SYMBOL and then (later in body) I tried to render it.

Can you please explain me, why is this happening and can you provide some tips, how can I solve this situation? Thank you very much.

Comment: The svg optimizer at https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/ yields the following error message - Load failed: Error in parsing SVG: Unbound namespace prefix: "xlink" Line: 4 Column: 36 Char. 

Something about your svg is not svg namespace standards compliant. What generated this svg code?

Comment: After trying for so long! found that your `SVG` is corrupted. It's not valid

Comment: you have the US flag in there and its still solid graphic, then the map is not outlined.

Comment: but when you will remove `visibility: hidden;` it works fine. How is that possible?

Comment: Im working on it now. will post something soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you have the first `SVG` the flag and part of the map weren't recognized as vector graphic and didn't get included in the `SVG`.

So I had to edit it again as vector graphic.

check this code:

```css
div {
  background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 100 58" style="enable-background:new 0 0 100 58;" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="icon">
 <g>
  <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M61.1,49.4c-3.9,2.5-8.4,3.8-13.4,3.8c-5.7,0-10.7-1.7-15.1-5.1c-0.3-0.3-0.8-0.2-1.1,0.1
   c-0.3,0.3-0.2,0.8,0.1,1.1c4.6,3.6,10,5.4,16,5.4c5.3,0,10-1.4,14.2-4c0.3-0.2,0.4-0.7,0.2-1C61.9,49.3,61.4,49.2,61.1,49.4z"/>
  <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M34,43.8c-0.2-0.3-0.7-0.4-1-0.2c-0.3,0.2-0.4,0.7-0.2,1l2.6,3.7c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2l3.6,2.4
   c0.1,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.4,0.1c0.2,0,0.4-0.1,0.5-0.2c0.3-0.2,0.3-0.6,0.1-0.9l-2.7-4.8l1.2-3.7c0-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.2l-0.1-4.1
   c0-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.4-0.6L33.9,34c-0.4-0.2-0.8-0.1-1,0.3c-0.2,0.4-0.1,0.8,0.3,1l4,2.2l0.1,3.5L36,45c-0.1,0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.6
   l1.3,2.4l-0.9-0.6L34,43.8z"/>
  <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M73.6,30C73.6,30,73.6,30,73.6,30c0-0.2,0.4-2.9,0-5.6c-1-6.5-3-10.6-7.2-14.9c-1-1-2-1.9-3.1-2.7
   c-1.3-1-2.7-1.8-4.2-2.5c0,0,0,0,0,0c0,0,0,0,0,0c-3.4-1.6-7.3-2.5-11.4-2.5c-1.1,0-2.2,0-3.2,0.1c0,0,0,0,0,0c0,0,0,0,0,0
   c-2,0.2-4,0.6-5.9,1.3C37.8,3.6,37,4,36.1,4.4c0,0,0,0,0,0c-2,1-3.8,2.2-5.4,3.6c0,0,0,0,0,0c0,0,0,0,0,0c0,0-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1
   c-0.6,0.5-1,0.9-1.4,1.3c-3.8,3.8-6.2,8.2-7.2,13.1c-0.1,0.4,0.2,0.8,0.6,0.9c0.1,0,0.1,0,0.2,0c0.3,0,0.7-0.2,0.7-0.6
   c1-4.6,3.3-8.8,6.9-12.4c0.3-0.4,0.7-0.8,1.2-1.1c0,0,0,0,0.1-0.1l3.9,0.3l-0.9,3.9l-2.8-1c-0.3-0.1-0.6,0-0.8,0.2l-1.4,1.5
   c-0.2,0.2-0.2,0.4-0.2,0.6c0,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.4,0.5l3.9,2.2v2.7l-2.2,0.7c-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.4,0.3l-3.3,5.5c-0.2,0.4-0.1,0.8,0.2,1
   c0.4,0.2,0.8,0.1,1-0.2l3.2-5.2l2.5-0.8c0.3-0.1,0.5-0.4,0.5-0.7v-3.7c0-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.4-0.7l-3.4-1.9l0.4-0.5l3.1,1.1
   c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.6,0c0.2-0.1,0.3-0.3,0.4-0.5L37,9.2c0-0.2,0-0.4-0.1-0.6c-0.1-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.5-0.3L33.1,8
   c1.1-0.8,2.2-1.5,3.4-2.1L39.4,7l-0.9,6c0,0.3,0.1,0.6,0.3,0.7c0.2,0.2,0.5,0.2,0.8,0.1l4.9-2.6c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.3-0.4l2.4-5.3
   c0.1-0.3,0.1-0.6-0.1-0.8L46,3.4c0.6,0,1.1,0,1.7,0c3.7,0,7.1,0.7,10.2,2.1L56,11l-1.5,0.6l-2.8-1.1c-0.3-0.1-0.6,0-0.8,0.2
   l-3.7,3.6c-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.4-0.2,0.6s0.2,0.4,0.4,0.6l2.5,1.4c0.3,0.2,0.8,0.1,1-0.2l0.8-1.2l0.8,0.6l-1.5,2.5l-1.6-0.9
   c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.6-0.1c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.2-0.4,0.4l-0.6,1.4l-3,1.4c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.2l-0.9,1.3c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.1,0.5
   l0.3,2.4c0,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.4,0.6c0.2,0.1,0.5,0.1,0.7,0l3.9-2.4l1.2,0.7c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1h2.9l2.1,1.5l-0.3,0.7
   c-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.6,0.2,0.8l4.6,4.5c0.1,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.2c0.1,0,0.3,0,0.4-0.1l3.7-2.4c0.2-0.1,0.3-0.4,0.3-0.6
   c0-0.2-0.1-0.5-0.3-0.6L61.7,26l1.7-2.9l1.1,1.9c0.1,0.3,0.4,0.4,0.7,0.4c0.3,0,0.5-0.2,0.6-0.5l1.5-4.6l4.9,9.9c0,0,0,0,0,0.1
   c0,0,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1c0,0,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1c0,0,0.1,0,0.1,0.1c0,0,0.1,0,0.1,0.1c0,0,0,0,0.1,0c0,0,0.1,0,0.1,0c0,0,0,0,0,0
   c0,0,0.1,0,0.1,0c0.1,0,0.1,0,0.2,0c0,0,0,0,0,0c0,0,0,0,0.1,0c0,0,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1c0,0,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1c0,0,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1
   C73.6,30.1,73.6,30.1,73.6,30z M43.6,10l-3.4,1.8L41,6.6c0.1-0.3-0.1-0.7-0.5-0.8L38.4,5c0.3-0.1,0.5-0.2,0.8-0.3
   c1.6-0.6,3.3-0.9,5.1-1.2l1.4,1.8L43.6,10z M67.1,17.5c-0.3,0-0.6,0.2-0.7,0.5l-1.5,4.7l-0.8-1.5c-0.1-0.2-0.4-0.4-0.6-0.4
   c-0.2,0-0.5,0.1-0.7,0.4l-2.7,4.5c-0.2,0.3-0.1,0.7,0.2,1l2.4,1.9l-2.3,1.5l-3.8-3.8l0.4-0.8c0.1-0.3,0-0.7-0.2-0.9l-2.8-2
   c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.1h-2.9l-1.4-0.8c-0.2-0.1-0.5-0.1-0.8,0l-3.3,2l-0.1-1l0.6-0.9l3-1.4c0.2-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.4-0.4l0.4-0.9
   l1.6,0.9c0.4,0.2,0.8,0.1,1-0.3l2.2-3.7c0.2-0.3,0.1-0.8-0.2-1l-2-1.4c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.6-0.1c-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.5,0.3l-0.9,1.3
   l-1-0.6l2.6-2.5l2.7,1.1c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.5,0l2.1-0.8c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.4-0.5l2-5.7c1.1,0.6,2.2,1.2,3.2,2c1,0.8,2,1.6,3,2.6
   c4,4,5.9,7.9,6.8,14c0.1,0.8,0.2,1.6,0.2,2.4l-4.5-9.1C67.7,17.7,67.4,17.5,67.1,17.5z"/>
  <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M40.4,33.3l3.7,3.2c0.2,0.2,0.4,0.2,0.7,0.2l2.3-0.6l3,9.9c0.1,0.3,0.3,0.5,0.6,0.5l1.3,0.1
   c0,0,0.1,0,0.1,0c0.2,0,0.4-0.1,0.6-0.2l4.4-4.9c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.3,0.2-0.5v-2.5l2.9-3.3c0.3-0.3,0.3-0.7,0-1l-6-6.5
   c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.2l-4.1-0.3l-0.5-1.2c-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.4-0.4c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.6,0l-4.9,2.4c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.3
   l-2.6,4C40,32.7,40.1,33.1,40.4,33.3z M44,29.4l4-1.9l0.3,0.8c0.1,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.5l4.3,0.3l5.3,5.8l-2.6,3
   c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.3-0.2,0.5v2.5l-3.9,4.4l-0.4,0L48.4,35c-0.1-0.4-0.5-0.6-0.9-0.5l-2.7,0.7l-2.9-2.5L44,29.4z"/>
  <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M59.2,41.8l-2.3,2.9c-0.3,0.3-0.2,0.8,0.1,1.1c0.1,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.2c0.2,0,0.4-0.1,0.6-0.3
   l2.3-2.9c0.3-0.3,0.2-0.8-0.1-1.1C59.9,41.4,59.4,41.5,59.2,41.8z"/>
  <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M69.7,27.2c-0.4-0.2-0.8-0.1-1,0.3l-0.7,1.2c-0.2,0.4-0.1,0.8,0.3,1c0.1,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.4,0.1
   c0.3,0,0.5-0.1,0.6-0.4l0.7-1.2C70.1,27.8,70,27.4,69.7,27.2z"/>
  <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M42.5,20.1l2.6-2.4c0.3-0.3,0.3-0.8,0-1.1s-0.8-0.3-1.1,0L41.5,19c-0.3,0.3-0.3,0.8,0,1.1
   c0.1,0.2,0.4,0.2,0.6,0.2C42.2,20.3,42.4,20.3,42.5,20.1z"/>
 </g>
 <g>
  <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M80.7,54.7c-2.5,0-4.5,0-5.8-0.1c-2.1-0.1-4.1-0.2-5.8-0.4c-1-0.2-1.8-0.5-2.5-1.1
   c-0.8-0.7-1.3-1.5-1.5-2.5c-0.2-1-0.4-2.2-0.5-3.7c-0.1-0.8-0.1-2-0.1-3.7c0-1.6,0-2.9,0.1-3.7c0.1-1.4,0.2-2.7,0.5-3.7
   c0.2-1,0.7-1.8,1.5-2.5c0.7-0.7,1.5-1.1,2.5-1.2c1.7-0.2,3.6-0.3,5.8-0.4h11.7c2.1,0.1,4,0.2,5.6,0.4c1,0.1,1.8,0.5,2.6,1.2
   c0.7,0.7,1.2,1.5,1.4,2.5c0.2,1.1,0.4,2.3,0.4,3.7c0.1,0.7,0.1,1.9,0.1,3.7c0,1.3,0,2.4-0.1,3.2c0,0.2,0,0.3,0,0.5
   c-0.1,1.4-0.2,2.7-0.5,3.7c-0.2,1-0.6,1.8-1.4,2.5c-0.8,0.6-1.6,1-2.5,1.1c-1.7,0.2-3.7,0.3-5.8,0.4
   C85.2,54.7,83.3,54.7,80.7,54.7z M86.7,33.3H75c-2.1,0.1-4,0.2-5.7,0.4c-0.6,0.1-1.2,0.3-1.6,0.8c-0.5,0.5-0.8,1-1,1.7
   c-0.2,0.9-0.4,2.1-0.4,3.5c-0.1,0.8-0.1,2-0.1,3.6c0,1.6,0,2.8,0.1,3.6c0.1,1.4,0.2,2.5,0.4,3.5c0.1,0.7,0.5,1.3,1,1.7
   c0.5,0.4,1.1,0.7,1.7,0.8c1.6,0.1,3.5,0.3,5.7,0.3c1.3,0.1,3.2,0.1,5.7,0.1c2.5,0,4.5,0,5.7-0.1c2.1-0.1,4-0.2,5.7-0.3
   c0.6-0.1,1.2-0.4,1.7-0.8c0.5-0.4,0.8-1,0.9-1.7c0.3-1,0.4-2.1,0.5-3.5c0,0,0-0.1,0-0.1c0-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.4
   c0.1-0.8,0.1-1.8,0.1-3.1c0-1.7,0-2.9-0.1-3.6c-0.1-1.4-0.2-2.5-0.4-3.5c-0.1-0.7-0.5-1.2-1-1.7c-0.5-0.4-1.1-0.7-1.7-0.8
   C90.6,33.5,88.7,33.4,86.7,33.3z"/>
 </g>
 <g>
  <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M76.7,48.7c-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.4-0.1C76.1,48.5,76,48.3,76,48V37.8c0-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.4-0.6
   s0.5-0.1,0.7,0l9.7,5.1c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.7s-0.2,0.5-0.4,0.7l-9.7,5.1C77,48.7,76.9,48.7,76.7,48.7z M77.5,39.1v7.7l7.4-3.8
   L77.5,39.1z"/>
 </g>
 <g>
  <circle style="fill:#FFFFFF;" cx="17.5" cy="39.6" r="14.3"/>
  <path style="fill:#EB2227;" d="M18.5,31.2H29c-0.7-0.9-1.4-1.7-2.3-2.4h-8.2V31.2z"/>
  <path style="fill:#EB2227;" d="M18.5,25.4v1h4.4C21.6,25.8,20.1,25.5,18.5,25.4z"/>
  <path style="fill:#303287;" d="M18.5,25.4c-0.3,0-0.7-0.1-1-0.1c-0.2,0-0.3,0-0.5,0l0,0h0.7l-0.5,0.4l0.2,0.6L16.8,26l-0.5,0.4
   l0.2-0.6L16,25.4c-0.8,0.1-1.6,0.2-2.3,0.5l0.2,0.5L13.3,26l-0.5,0.4l0.1-0.3c-0.4,0.1-0.8,0.3-1.2,0.5l0.1,0.5h0.7l-0.5,0.4
   l0.2,0.6l-0.5-0.4L11,28l0.2-0.6l-0.5-0.4h0.7l0.1-0.4c-3,1.4-5.4,3.8-6.9,6.7l0.1,0.4h0.7l-0.5,0.4l0.2,0.6l-0.5-0.4L4,34.8
   l0.1-0.5c-0.6,1.4-0.9,2.9-1,4.5h0.5l-0.5,0.4c0,0,0,0.1,0,0.1l0.2,0.5l-0.2-0.1c0,0.3,0,0.7,0.1,1h15.3V25.4z M5.1,38.2l-0.5-0.4
   L4,38.2l0.2-0.6l-0.5-0.4h0.7l0.2-0.6l0.2,0.6h0.7l-0.5,0.4L5.1,38.2z M6.9,39.9l-0.5-0.4l-0.5,0.4L6,39.2l-0.5-0.4h0.7l0.2-0.6
   l0.2,0.6h0.7l-0.5,0.4L6.9,39.9z M6.6,35.9l0.2,0.6l-0.5-0.4l-0.5,0.4L6,35.9l-0.5-0.4h0.7l0.2-0.6l0.2,0.6h0.7L6.6,35.9z
    M6.6,32.5l0.2,0.6l-0.5-0.4l-0.5,0.4L6,32.5l-0.5-0.4h0.7l0.2-0.6l0.2,0.6h0.7L6.6,32.5z M8.6,38.2l-0.5-0.4l-0.5,0.4l0.2-0.6
   l-0.5-0.4h0.7l0.2-0.6l0.2,0.6h0.7l-0.5,0.4L8.6,38.2z M8.4,34.2l0.2,0.6l-0.5-0.4l-0.5,0.4l0.2-0.6l-0.5-0.4h0.7l0.2-0.6l0.2,0.6
   h0.7L8.4,34.2z M8.4,30.8l0.2,0.6L8.1,31l-0.5,0.4l0.2-0.6l-0.5-0.4h0.7l0.2-0.6l0.2,0.6h0.7L8.4,30.8z M10.3,39.9l-0.5-0.4
   l-0.5,0.4l0.2-0.6L9,38.9h0.7l0.2-0.6l0.2,0.6h0.7l-0.5,0.4L10.3,39.9z M10.1,35.9l0.2,0.6l-0.5-0.4l-0.5,0.4l0.2-0.6L9,35.5h0.7
   l0.2-0.6l0.2,0.6h0.7L10.1,35.9z M10.1,32.5l0.2,0.6l-0.5-0.4l-0.5,0.4l0.2-0.6L9,32.1h0.7l0.2-0.6l0.2,0.6h0.7L10.1,32.5z
    M10.1,29.1l0.2,0.6l-0.5-0.4l-0.5,0.4l0.2-0.6L9,28.7h0.7l0.2-0.6l0.2,0.6h0.7L10.1,29.1z M12.1,38.2l-0.5-0.4L11,38.2l0.2-0.6
   l-0.5-0.4h0.7l0.2-0.6l0.2,0.6h0.7l-0.5,0.4L12.1,38.2z M11.9,34.2l0.2,0.6l-0.5-0.4L11,34.8l0.2-0.6l-0.5-0.4h0.7l0.2-0.6
   l0.2,0.6h0.7L11.9,34.2z M11.9,30.8l0.2,0.6L11.6,31L11,31.4l0.2-0.6l-0.5-0.4h0.7l0.2-0.6l0.2,0.6h0.7L11.9,30.8z M13.8,39.9
   l-0.5-0.4l-0.5,0.4l0.2-0.6l-0.5-0.4h0.7l0.2-0.6l0.2,0.6h0.7l-0.5,0.4L13.8,39.9z M13.6,35.9l0.2,0.6l-0.5-0.4l-0.5,0.4l0.2-0.6
   l-0.5-0.4h0.7l0.2-0.6l0.2,0.6h0.7L13.6,35.9z M13.6,32.5l0.2,0.6l-0.5-0.4l-0.5,0.4l0.2-0.6l-0.5-0.4h0.7l0.2-0.6l0.2,0.6h0.7
   L13.6,32.5z M13.6,29.1l0.2,0.6l-0.5-0.4l-0.5,0.4l0.2-0.6l-0.5-0.4h0.7l0.2-0.6l0.2,0.6h0.7L13.6,29.1z M15.6,38.2l-0.5-0.4
   l-0.5,0.4l0.2-0.6l-0.5-0.4h0.7l0.2-0.6l0.2,0.6h0.7l-0.5,0.4L15.6,38.2z M15.4,34.2l0.2,0.6l-0.5-0.4l-0.5,0.4l0.2-0.6l-0.5-0.4
   h0.7l0.2-0.6l0.2,0.6h0.7L15.4,34.2z M15.4,30.8l0.2,0.6L15.1,31l-0.5,0.4l0.2-0.6l-0.5-0.4h0.7l0.2-0.6l0.2,0.6h0.7L15.4,30.8z
    M15.4,27.4l0.2,0.6l-0.5-0.4L14.5,28l0.2-0.6l-0.5-0.4h0.7l0.2-0.6l0.2,0.6h0.7L15.4,27.4z M17.3,39.9l-0.5-0.4l-0.5,0.4l0.2-0.6
   l-0.5-0.4h0.7l0.2-0.6l0.2,0.6h0.7l-0.5,0.4L17.3,39.9z M17.1,35.9l0.2,0.6l-0.5-0.4l-0.5,0.4l0.2-0.6l-0.5-0.4h0.7l0.2-0.6
   l0.2,0.6h0.7L17.1,35.9z M17.1,32.5l0.2,0.6l-0.5-0.4l-0.5,0.4l0.2-0.6l-0.5-0.4h0.7l0.2-0.6l0.2,0.6h0.7L17.1,32.5z M17.1,29.1
   l0.2,0.6l-0.5-0.4l-0.5,0.4l0.2-0.6l-0.5-0.4h0.7l0.2-0.6l0.2,0.6h0.7L17.1,29.1z"/>
  <path style="fill:#EB2227;" d="M5.8,47.8c0.6,0.9,1.4,1.7,2.2,2.4H27c0.8-0.7,1.5-1.5,2.2-2.4H5.8z"/>
  <path style="fill:#EB2227;" d="M4.4,45.5h26.1c0.4-0.8,0.6-1.6,0.8-2.4H3.6C3.8,43.9,4.1,44.7,4.4,45.5z"/>
  <path style="fill:#EB2227;" d="M18.5,40.7h13.2c0-0.4,0.1-0.7,0.1-1.1c0-0.5,0-0.9-0.1-1.3H18.5V40.7z"/>
  <path style="fill:#EB2227;" d="M30.4,33.5H18.5V36h12.8C31.1,35.1,30.8,34.3,30.4,33.5z"/>
  <path style="fill:#EB2227;" d="M17.5,53.9c2.1,0,4.2-0.5,6-1.3h-12C13.3,53.5,15.3,53.9,17.5,53.9z"/>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Happy to help! :)